# Ruby Regex extract numbers

Tags: ruby

I wanted to grab the numbers between the td 's and store it in data. I used the * to represent the information I want to get.

```
data = data.match(<td class="yfnc_tabledata1">*</td>)
```

Comment: Are you trying to use regex with HTML?  You should use a proper parser if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex expression for grabing numbers in general is a very complicated one, because numbers come in all kinds of shapes and colors. You need to decide what all kinds of numbers are you interested in, integers, with/without sign, floats, exponential notation, accept/not accept leading +... Try to look at http://regexlib.com for the regex that fits your needs. And, of course, as suggested in the comments, please don't parse markup langugages with regexen.

For example, from the site cited above, you can find regex:

```
/^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

With description: This matches any real number, with optional decimal point and numbers after the decimal, and optional positive (+) or negative (-) designation.

It is up to you whether you want to enclose your regex in `^` and `$`, or what requirements will you have for eg. whitespaces in front or behind your numbers etc. Note that the regex example I gave only *matches* (ie. validates) those numbers, to actually grab them, you would have to care about those `[+-]` signs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the regex expression for grabbing one or more numbers is `/>(\d+)</` which means one or more numbers (I believe, not too good at regex). I use http://nokogiri.org/ for html parsing though.

Comment: I don’t think `>` and `<` are special characters in Ruby regexes. You probably want either `^` and `$`, if the first line of the string has to be a series of digits, or `\A` and `\Z`, if the whole string has to be a series of digits.

Comment: excellent recommendation